# Attachments no longer linked to Test Case step after migration

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

After migrating a Test Case work item type, the attachments are no longer linked to the individual test case steps.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOnza.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjj23.png)

The attachments are being migrated however, i.e. they are part of the work item attachment list.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments to test steps are not currently supported.

You can submit a PR with that feature.